# TimeOut value in AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout

Can I configure a timeout in AWS ALB for front-end connection? I am not talking about connection level idle timeout. I am asking about transaction level timeout. For example, I configure timeout of 60 seconds somewhere in the load balancer and send a transaction to ALB which is then sent to an appropriate target. If a response from the target is not received in 60 seconds then the user gets a preconfigured response from ALB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `Connection idle timeout` setting on ALB, which by default is 60 seconds. can be increased to 4000 seconds.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout) is how we can increase it from console.

On the Description tab, choose Edit attributes and enter Idle timeout in seconds.

Comment: Is this at the load balancer level? What if I have multiple target groups registered with my load balancer and I need different connection timeout setting for different groups?

Comment: This is a timeout for connection from client to ALB and ALB to Target. I don't know if there is any such setting at Target group level!

Comment: Each target group may sometimes need different idle timeouts and this I believe is not supported yet. I have a similar requirements and there is way to do this.

Comment: Even target group isn't really precise enough. You'd have to completely rearchitect an application that needs differing timeouts by path.

Comment: It is possible to have different timeout for different routes. you can create ingress group and attach multiple routes/ingress to same group. in fact, this way , you can apply different attributes for different routes.

 alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: app-ingress-group
 alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '10'

then you can speficy required values in timeout for each route  based on requirement
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: "idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=1200"

Answer (score 0):

I was going through comments in above answer, It is possible to have different timeout for each route through ingress group. I was able to achieve this. In my case, we have Kubernetes templates and ingress which creates ALB. You can bind different route under same ingress group and hence it will be in single ALB. Please refer below code.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: student-webapp
  labels:
    app: student-app
    name: student-webapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: student-ingress-group
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: "idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=120"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /practice/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: practice-api
                port:
                  number: 8080
---------------------------------

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: student-webapp
  labels:
    app: student-app
    name: student-webapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: student-ingress-group
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '300'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: "idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=180"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /study/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: study-api
                port:
                  number: 8080
```